# Example of Invariant Functor?

Tags: haskell, functor

I'm reading [documentation on monad layers package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/layers-0.1/docs/Documentation-Layers-Overview.html) and my brain is going to boil up.

In the `mmtl` section of this document the author talks about *invariant functor*. It's method `invmap` is like `fmap` of `Functor` but it takes an inverse morphism `(b -> a)` also. I understand why author says that `hoist` of `MFunctor` is more powerful than `tmap` of `Invariant` but i don't see what's the point of that inverse morphism.

Is there any example of an `Invariant` which can't be an instance of `Functor`?

Comment: `Endo a` from `Data.Monoid`?

Comment: Yeah, `Endo` should be invariant.

Comment: I think it would be useful to look into `Contravariant`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a standard place where `Invariant` shows up---higher order abstract syntax (HOAS) for embedding lambda calculus. In HOAS we like to write expression types like

```
data ExpF a 
  = App a a
  | Lam (a -> a)

-- ((\x . x) (\x . x)) is sort of like
ex :: ExpF (ExpF a)
ex = App (Lam id) (Lam id)

-- we can use tricky types to make this repeat layering of `ExpF`s easier to work with
```

We'd love for this type to have structure like `Functor` but sadly it cannot be since `Lam` has `a`s in both positive and negative position. So instead we define

```
instance Invariant ExpF where
  invmap ab ba (App x y) = App (ab x) (ab y)
  invmap ab ba (Lam aa)  = Lam (ab . aa . ba)
```

This is really tragic because what we would really like to do is to fold this `ExpF` type in on itself to form a recursive expression tree. If it were a `Functor` that'd be obvious, but since it's not we get some very ugly, challenging constructions.

To resolve this, you add another type parameter and call it Parametric HOAS

```
data ExpF b a
  = App a a
  | Lam (b -> a)
  deriving Functor
```

And we end up finding that we can build a free monad atop this type using its `Functor` instance where binding is variable substitution. Very nice!

Comment: Wouldn't you also want `Var b` since `ExpF b a` is only a `Fix` away from PHOAS

Comment: I was following https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/edwardk/phoas. At this point, `ExpF` is essentially just a `Free` away from the goal, though.