# How to write map/fmap analogue (a->b) -> F m a -> F m b

Tags: haskell

Good day/night everyone!
I have type:

```
data FixItem m a = KeepItem|SkipItem|FixItem (m (a -> a))
fixItem f = FixItem $ pure f
```

and I want to write function `mapFix :: (a -> b) -> FixItem m a -> FixItem m b`. When I try:

```
mapFix f SkipItem = SkipItem -- good
mapFix f KeepItem = fixItem f -- error "rigid type"!!!
mapFix f (FixItem mf) = FixItem $ pure (.) <*> (pure f) <*> mf -- too!
```

So, I get error:

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘b’ with ‘a’
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          mapFix :: forall (m :: * -> *) a b.
                    Applicative m =>
                    (a -> b) -> FixItem m a -> FixItem m b
        at src/test.hs:235:11
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          mapFix :: forall (m :: * -> *) a b.
                    Applicative m =>
                    (a -> b) -> FixItem m a -> FixItem m b
        at src/test.hs:235:11
      Expected type: b -> b
        Actual type: a -> b
    • In the first argument of ‘fixItem’, namely ‘f’
      In the expression: fixItem f
      In an equation for ‘mapFix’: mapFix f KeepItem = fixItem f
    • Relevant bindings include
        f :: a -> b (bound at src/test.hs:236:8)
        mapFix :: (a -> b) -> FixItem m a -> FixItem m b
          (bound at src/test.hs:236:1)
```

How to write mapFix or implement Functor instance for such type (FixItem fixes `a` to `a`, not to `b`, i.e. fix is `a -> a`, not `a -> b`)?

Answer (score 4):

You can't implement `Functor` type class for your data type. It's because of
`a -> a` inside one of your constructors. When you have functions, you should be more careful. But in short, you have type variable `a` in contravariant position so you can't implement `Functor` over this type variable.

Though you can implement [`Invariant`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/invariant-0.4.2/docs/Data-Functor-Invariant.html#t:Invariant) for your data type. Because `a` in both *covariant* and *contravariant* positions, your data type is invariant functor.

Can help you:

[Example of Invariant Functor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22103445/example-of-invariant-functor)

[What is a contravariant functor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034077/what-is-a-contravariant-functor)

[Some blog post](https://michaelochurch.wordpress.com/2016/01/01/insights-into-why-a-contravariant-type-cant-be-a-haskell-functor/)

Comment: I suspected that Functor is impossible, so is this mean that `mapFix` function is impossible too?  Btw, when I changed type to `FixItem m a b = FixItem (m (a -> b))|SkipItem|KeepItem` and try to implement Functor, I get again errors about right type 'a'...

Comment: Hmm, I got it: composition of `pure f` and `mf` hides `a -> b` in FixITem, while FixItem supports `a -> a` only. So, mapFix is impossible. But is it possible to implement `FixITem m a b = FixITem (m (a -> b))|...` Functor instance?

Comment: Ah, OK, done :) `fmap f (FixItem mf) = FixItem $ pure (.) <*> (pure f) <*> mf`. Thanks!

Comment: @Paul-AG Yes, functor is impossible in some theoretical sense. It means that `mapFix` function is impossible as well :( If you change `a -> a` into `a -> b` and have type `FixItem m a b` than you can write `mapFix` which when given `b -> c` function can map `FixItem m a b` to `FixItem m a c` because `b` type variable is in covariant position.